# Scale and stay at Z position

Tags: modeling

I have a cube positioned at Z-axis = 0 like this

[image]

Now I scale the cube 3 times and then I get this

[image]

How to scale that the cube is enlarged 3 times along the Z axis and stays at Z = 0 ? Like this

[image]

Comment: You may put the origin point at the bottom of the cube (in the same place where your cursor is in the third picture) and then scale. In Edit Mode place the cursor at the bottom of the object and then in Object Mode press Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C--->Origin to 3D Cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose "Pivot point" for manipulate with objects. Default is "Median Point", which is Origin in your case. You need switch Pivot point to "3D Cursor"

[image: Pivot point]